# Best practise referencing objects

Tags: c#, xna, pass-by-reference

The question itself is not directly related to XNA but the issue i have is. I am interested in the performance effect for referencing objects to methods/functions. For instance, in XNA i often see code referencing the complete Game1 object when there is only the need for a specific value or object like the GraphicsDevice, or just the viewport lying much deeper in the hierarchy. I always reference the specific value or object because i think this is best practise, often i have to go back and add another value if needed.

So what is best practise for referencing values and objects to methods/functions? Does it matter much or is it just somekind of pointer? So a pointer to simple int or a huge object would be the same? Things get more obvious when this gets stored in another class in a property, there needs to be another memory block reserved for the property, right?

Comment: You should not reference the hole objects only and use just a specific property. You approach is the correct one, you should not even expose properties, methods of an object if they are not meant to be used by others (encapsulation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Referencing' an object for the sake of accessing only a small portion of it's proporties/methods is not good practice. It is much better to expose the required functionality, make it static, then do something like:

```
// Calling a static method
Game1.DoSomething();
// Accessing a static property
int test += Game1.MyInt;
```

I think the reason why you are seeing XNA code samples referencing the whole object is because a number of XNA programmers do not have object orientated development backgrounds compared to straight-up C# developers, and are thus unaware of best practices for using the language efficiently.

Comment: You say efficient but are there any tests on how much this influences performance? What is the difference between referencing a couple of ints 60 times per second vs a complete object consisting of a couple hundred Bytes?

Comment: I don't know of any tests that I could link you to. I doubt there would be noticable difference in time. By efficent I talk in terms of encapsulation and doing more with less lines of code. Why, for example, create a new object that points to an existing area of memory on the heap? We could skip that and expose what we need and access it without having to create a new object.

Comment: "Why, for example, create a new object..." It doesn't create a new object. It simply passes a reference to the already exsisting object. It is actually about as performance efficient as can be. Unfortunately it tightly couples the calling object to the passed object which can be risky when working in an environment with lots of devs modifing all the code. (Uncle Bob would not like it)

Comment: @SteveH So if you need a fixed object in a constructor, but also in a method that will be running many times a second it is better to pass the reference each time to both the constructor and the method? Or would it be better to store the object as a property in the constructor?

Comment: I would pass a reference to it in the constructor and set it to a local variable. like this:  http://pastebin.com/BaXy8m3P